# Manifest file not found

Tags: android, android-studio

what to do if i am not getting Manifest file in my Android Studio? Please help me to get out from this Problem. I have already installed Android Studio 3 to 4 times but was unable to find the manifest file without which i am stuck to do coding.

Comment: `control + shift + F` and search `manifest`

Comment: If you have created the project in Android Studio or even Eclipse, you will always have `AndroidManifest.xml`. You may use your file browser (Windows Explorer, if you're on Windows) to search and find it inside the project location.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can find manefests file given below